# Why does ofstream require a flush?

Tags: c++, file, stream, standard-library

If I run the following code, no file is created at all:

```
std::ofstream outputFile(strOutputLocation.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
outputFile.write((const char*)lpResLock, dwSizeRes);
outputFile.close();
```

However, if I add a flush() before the close, it works:

```
std::ofstream outputFile(strOutputLocation.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
outputFile.write((const char*)lpResLock, dwSizeRes);
outputFile.flush();
outputFile.close();
```

Does the standard library actually require this, or is it a bug in the Visual C++ CRT?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bug. Reading §27.8.1.10/4, abridged:

> `void close();`
>   Effects: Calls `rdbuf()->close()`...

What does `rdbuf()->close()` do? According to §27.8.1.3/6, abridged, emphasis mine:

> `basic_filebuf<charT,traits>* close();`
>   If `is_open() == false`, returns a null pointer. **If a put area exists, calls `overflow(EOF)` to flush characters.** ...

That is, it's suppose to flush. (Indeed, the call to `flush()` ultimately does the same thing.)

---

Note the call to `close()` itself isn't needed, as the destructor of `basic_ofstream` will call `close()`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking the file before you exit from the program? OS will buffer all IO, so may not see any data(unless you flush) in the file before you exit.