# Calculating prime numbers using multi threading

Tags: c++

I started to work with threads recently and I tried to run a simple program that uses threads but I get really strange output.
The program writes the prime numbers in the given range with N(parameter to the function)number of threads into the file "PRIMES.txt", if the `range <= 1000` the output is fine but if the range is bigger, then the output is something like :

`‰‱′″‵‷ㄱㄠ″㜱ㄠ‹㌲㈠‹ㄳ㌠‷ㄴ㐠″㜴㔠″㤵㘠‱㜶㜠‱㌷㜠‹㌸㠠‹㜹ㄠ㄰ㄠ㌰ㄠ㜰ㄠ㤰ㄠ㌱ㄠ㜲ㄠㄳㄠ㜳ㄠ㤳ㄠ㤴ㄠㄵㄠ㜵ㄠ㌶ㄠ㜶ㄠ㌷ㄠ㤷... (much longer)`

What would be the problem?

Here is my code :

threads.h :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void writePrimesToFile(int begin, int end, ofstream& file);
void callWritePrimesMultipleThreads(int begin, int end, string filePath, int N);
```

threads.cpp :

```
#include "Threads.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>

mutex mtx;

void PrimesToFile(int begin, int end, ofstream& file)
{
bool isPrime;
string Primes;
int count = 0;
mtx.lock();
cout << "Thread is running" << endl;
    for (int i = begin; i < end; i++)
    {
        isPrime = true;
        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (i%j == 0)
                isPrime = false;
        }
        if (isPrime)
        {
            Primes.append(to_string(i));
            Primes.append(" ");
        }
    }
file.write(Primes.c_str(), Primes.length());
mtx.unlock();
}

void WritePrimesMultipleThreads(int begin, int end, string filePath, int N)
{
    ofstream OP;
    OP.open(filePath);
    int lastPos = 0;
    int destPos = end / N;
    thread* TV = new thread[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        TV[i] = thread(PrimesToFile, lastPos, destPos, ref(OP));
        lastPos = destPos;
        destPos += end / N;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        TV[i].join();
}
```

Starting point :

```
#include "Threads.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>

void main()
{
    WritePrimesMultipleThreads(1, 10000, "PRIMES.txt", 5);
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: C++ - Why are you using `void main`?

Comment: I think you're creating too many threads. Try to fix them at certain level. Why would you need 1000 threads? This is not solution for the problem, but I think this worth considering. [How many threads is too many?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481970/how-many-threads-is-too-many) Note that question I'm referring to is about servers. Also you don't delete them.

Comment: I created only 5 as mentioned in the call    WritePrimesMultipleThreads(1, 10000, "PRIMES.txt", 5); and when I try to delete them it throws an exception.

Comment: Your program is effectively singlethreaded since the mutex is locked throughout the function.

Comment: changing stream to std::strstream solved the problem partially, but if code will be corrected as @molbdnilo says, your primes won't be sorted, something like 79 83 89 6007 8009 4001 (from my output). Despite that, rubbish at the end still exists.

Answer (score 1):

Hours of debugging turned out to be in wrong implementation of std::ofstream. Just outputting at the beginning `OP << "\n"` solved the problem. Compiler is MSVC 2015 update 1. More about about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036878/why-does-ofstream-require-a-flush). Additionally, you have resource leak, single threading when it is not really intended to, not efficient algorithm of finding primes in a range, compiling errors in your posted code, unnecessary writePrimesToFile function and header files in your header file, you're `using using namespace std` and may be more problems. I recommend you posting your code at [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to make the code better, because solving this problem is not enough to solve the original problem.
EDIT: You need to flush the stream every time you done writing something.